# Video.js remove poster when using currentTime before video starts

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have a playlist of videos, with a list of each video in a sidebar. When I click on the name of the video I want to load in the sidebar, the player switches the current video to the one I just clicked.

Some videos have sections, and those sections need to start playing at a certain time in the video. For example, I have a video with 2 sections, Section 1 starts at 0:00, but when I click on "Section 2" in the sidebar, the video should start playing at 1:30 seconds into the video.

Now I got this working with the following code, but the poster image is still playing over the video when I click on Section 2 which should start playing in the middle of the video. **How can I get rid of the poster image when starting a video with currentTime offset?**

```
(function($) {

    var current, gototime;
    var istime = false;

    // video.js object
    var $player = videojs('ppi-video');

    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var attr = $(this).attr('data-video');
        var time = $(this).attr('data-time');

        if(typeof time !== 'undefined' && time !== false) {
            istime = true;
            gototime = time;
        }else {
            istime = false;
            gototime = undefined;
        }

        // If link has data-video attribute... continue
        if(typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
            if( current == attr ) return;

            var image_path = "images/screens/";
            var content_path = "source/";

            // Wait till player is ready
            $player.ready(function() {
                // Hide the player?
                $("#ppi-video_html5_api").fadeOut(400, function() {
                        // Change poster
                        $("#ppi-video_html5_api").attr('poster', image_path + attr + ".jpg");
                        $player.poster(image_path + attr + ".jpg");
                });

                $player.src([
                    { type: "video/mp4", src: content_path + attr + ".mp4" },
                    { type: "video/webm", src: content_path + attr + ".webm" },
                ]);

                // Set the currently playing variable
                current = attr;

                $("#ppi-video_html5_api").fadeIn();

            });
        }

    });

    function updateVideo() {
        if( istime ) {
            $player.currentTime(gototime);
            $player.ready(function() {
                    /**
                     * Trying to get rid of poster here, but not working
                     */
                $("#ppi-video_html5_api").attr('poster', '');
                $player.poster('');
                $player.play();
            });
        }else {
            $player.currentTime(0);
        }
    }

    // update video when metadata has loaded
    $player.on('loadedmetadata', updateVideo);


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on Chrome and Firefox, setting `currentTime()` needs to be delayed a bit. What I did was call `play()` and then `pause()` to remove the poster before the video starts. Then I set a timeout of 200 milliseconds which has a callback which then calls `currentTime()`.

Kind of a makeshift workaround but it is working nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same situation where i needed to programmatically hide the poster image. (i wanted the posterimage to hide on drag of a custom scrubbar)

I found two ways that might help someone else who is in the same situation (i know this is an old post, but i came across it looking for an answer).
First and most simply you can hide the poster image using css:

```
.vjs-poster.vjs-poster.vjs-poster {
  display: none;
}
// specificity bumped for default css, your mileage may vary.
```

However because i wanted this to be done on drag event i figured i might as well just use js:

```
  player.posterImage.hide();
```